# Isomorphism of polynomial rings implying isomorphism of the coefficient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings. Let $x, y$ be indeterminates, and assume that one has an isomorphism $R[x] \rightarrow S[y]$ (not necessarily mapping $x$ to $y$ of course). Does this imply $R \cong S$? If not, what is a counterexample?

This may seem like a homework problem, but is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was settled in the negative by M. Hochster in 1972. His paper can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-034-01/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3/S0002-9939-1972-0294325-3.pdf).

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: settled in the sense: There are counterexamples.